# Getthe percentage difference between two numbers JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I need to get the percentage between two numbers like YouTube (likes and dislikes).

YouTube gets the number of likes and dislikes to set a percentage to progress bar like this picture:

[image]

I need to make something the same.

I have tried doing this but failed.

```js
function myFunction() {
var A = 591;
var B = 25;
var percent = 100 * Math.abs( (A - B) / ( (A+B)/2 ) );
  document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].textContent = percent; 
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: How should your result look like?

Comment: @Alex I just need to get the percentage to add it as a width for my progress bar like Youtube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...!

```
function myFunction() {
  const A = 591;
  const B = 25;
  const percent = 100 * A / (A + B)

  document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].textContent = percent; 
}
```